# HTML Table vertically rather than horizontally?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've got this table, and in this table are 4 columns, like this:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|
data 1  data 2  data 3  data 4
```

But how do I get it like this?

```
Column1| data 1
Column2| data 2
Column3| data 3
Column4| data 4
```

This is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <td>Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the th in the table rows

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <th>Column 1</th>
       <td>Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Column 2</th>
       <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <td>Data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 3</th>
        <td>Data 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 4</th>
        <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe scope attribute can help you?

```
<table>
    <tr scope="row">
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Some content</td>
       <td>Some content</td>
       <td>Some content</td>
       <td>Some content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800659/table-vertical-header), you get another solution by CSS.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below pattern **But** i'll suggest you to use css tables : [Page layout, Divs instead of Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796884/page-layout-divs-instead-of-tables/20796930#20796930)

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <th>Column1</th><td>data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Column1</th><td>data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Column1</th><td>data 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Column1</th><td>data 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting CSS tables. They are meant to be used for layout, not organising tabular data.